# What lens can I use on my Samsung wb1100f 35mm camera?

Tags: lens, point-and-shoot, samsung

[image]

I have a 35x optical zoom 16.4 megapixel Samsung WB1100F smart camera. What lenses can I use with this?

Answer (score 5):

Your camera does not have an interchangeable lens. The current lens is permanently fixed to the camera, and you can't change it to use another one. If you want to be able to swap lenses, you need to have an interchangeable lens camera.

Answer (score 2):

Your camera's main lens is permanently attached to your camera and is not considered interchangeable.

There are some non-interchangeable lens cameras with filter threads on the front of the lens that can be used to attach "close up filters" or "wide angle filters" that allow one to focus at a closer minimum distance for macro work or allow a wider field of view, respectively.

But your camera does not have any such filter threads on the front of the lens barrel and thus your use of such 'lenses' isn't really practical.